# Explanation of this integration passages

Tags: real-analysis, convolution, fractional-calculus

Let
$$u(x)\in L^1_s(\mathbb{R}^n) = \left\{ u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n; s\in(0,1); \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|u(x)|}{1 + |x|^{n+2s}}\ \text{d}x < +\infty \right\} $$

And let
$$A_r(y) = 
\begin{cases} 
C \dfrac{r^{2s}}{(|y|^2- r^2)^2|y|^n} & y\in\mathbb{R}^n\smallsetminus \bar{B}_r
\\\\
0 & y\in \bar{B}_r
\end{cases}
$$

where $C$ is a constant. Also it holds $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} A_r = 1$.

So now my problem: $u(x)$ is such that $u(x) = A_r * u(x)$ (convolution). This property is called $s$-mean.

I cannot procede forward in understanding why

$$u(x) - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n / B_r} A_r(y) u(x-y)\ \text{d}y = C r^{2s} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n / B_r} \frac{u(x) - u(x-y)}{(|y|^2- r^2)^2|y|^n}\ \text{d}y$$

Which more clearly: why can we just take $u(x)$ inside the fraction, in the integral, at the numerator in such way?

Also they say that since $r > 0$ (which is also arbitrary small) we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n / B_r} \frac{u(x) - u(x-y)}{(|y|^2- r^2)^2|y|^n}\ \text{d}y = 0$$

Can someone please provide me some clarification/motivation?

Thank you!

Comment: It appears that your first line of "displayed" MathJax was set in inline rather than display only because you didn't know how to put $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ in MathJax code. See my edits. I also changed the capital "w" in "where" to lower case. I had some uncertainty about the strange notation $\mathbb R^n\not\ \bar{B}_r,$ but I changed it to $\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus\bar{B}_r.\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you so much for the edits. I had problems indeed in writing those parts for I am used to different TeX commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a small typo: $$ A_r(y) = \frac{Cr^{2s}}{(\vert y \vert^2-r^2)^s \vert y \vert^n} \qquad \text{in } \mathbb R^n \setminus B_r.$$ (Note the power of $s$ in the denominator instead of 2). As you have noted $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}A_r(y)\,dy=1 $$ so $$u(x) =u(x)\int_{\mathbb R^n}A_r(y)\,dy = \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_r}  \frac{Cr^{2s}u(x)}{(\vert y \vert^2-r^2)^s \vert y \vert^n} \, dy.$$ Thus, \begin{align*}u(x)-(A_r\ast u)(x)&=u(x)-\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_r} A_r(y)u(x-y)\,dy \\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_r}  \frac{Cr^{2s}u(x)}{(\vert y \vert^2-r^2)^s \vert y \vert^n} \, dy-\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_r} A_r(y)u(x-y)\,dy \\
&=Cr^{2s}\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_r}\frac{u(x)-u(x-y)}{(\vert y \vert^2-r^2)^s \vert y \vert^n} \, dy
\end{align*} as required.

---

For your second question, what you have stated is not true in general. I think what you are trying to say is $$\lim_{r\to0^+}Cr^{2s}\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_r}\frac{u(x)-u(x-y)}{(\vert y \vert^2-r^2)^s \vert y \vert^n} \, dy=0,$$that is, $ u(x) = \lim_{r\to0^+} (A_r \ast u)(x). $ In fact a more general statement holds: \begin{align*}
\frac{u(x)-(A_r\ast u)(x)}{r^{2s}} &= C\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_r}\frac{u(x)-u(x-y)}{(\vert y \vert^2-r^2)^s \vert y \vert^n} \, dy \to (-\Delta)^su(x) 
\end{align*} as $r\to0^+$ where $(-\Delta)^su(x)$ is the fractional Laplacian (of course assuming $u$ has enough regularity for this to exist). To prove this use dominated convergence and the definition of the fractional Laplacian.

As an extra note, it is well-known that if what you said is true $(u(x)=(A_r \ast u)(x)$ for all $r>0$ sufficiently small) then this is equivalent to $(-\Delta)^su(x)=0$. This is the s-harmonic analogue of the mean value formula for harmonic functions. For more details you should check out Chapter 15 of [Fractional Thoughts](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.03347.pdf).

Comment: Very useful indeed! Thank you!